# How to enable images upload from computer using Tinymces text editor?

Tags: php, ajax, tinymce, codeigniter-2, tinymce-4

Tinymce!,

Dear Exert,

I'm currently used Tinymce text editor for my web design but it doesn't work with images upload from computer.
below is source code that I copy from other tutorial But I don't know how to modify or to enable images upload from computer when user edit or insert some images to my database 
Please check it and help

```
<script type="text/javascript">
        tinymce.init({

            selector: "textarea",
            theme: "modern",
            width: "630",
            height: "auto",
            plugins : "pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount,advlist,autosave,paste,fullscreen,noneditable,contextmenu",
            theme_advanced_buttons1_add_before : "newdocument,separator",
            theme_advanced_buttons1_add : "fontselect,fontsizeselect",
            theme_advanced_buttons2_add : "separator,forecolor,backcolor,liststyle",
            theme_advanced_buttons2_add_before: "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,separator,",
            theme_advanced_buttons3_add_before : "tablecontrols,separator",
            theme_advanced_buttons3_add : "flash,advhr,separator,fullscreen",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
            theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
            extended_valid_elements : "hr[class|width|size|noshade]",
            file_browser_callback : "image",
            paste_use_dialog : false,
            theme_advanced_resizing : true,
            theme_advanced_resize_horizontal : true,
            apply_source_formatting : true,
            force_br_newlines : true,
            force_p_newlines : false,
            relative_urls : true,
            toolbar: "insertfile | image| responsivefilemanager| undo redo | styleselect | bold italic | alignleft aligncenter alignright alignjustify | bullist numlist outdent indent | link image" || "print preview media | forecolor backcolor emoticons",
            plugins: "image",
            image_advtab:true,  
            image_list: [
                {title: 'My image 1', value: 'public_html/upload/'},
                {title: 'My image 2', value: 'public_html/upload/'}
            ]
            });
    </script>
```

It is work fine with text feature but it don't work for images upload 
Example: When I click on insert images/edit images->popup load than click on image icon for choosing a image but it doesn't show any thing

Thanks for help

Comment: Can you narrow your question down further than "it doesn't work" at all? Any errors? Any examples in the tutorial you followed that aren't working as you expected with the images?

Comment: sorry for miss it work at about other feature but it don't work only with images upload when I click on insert/edit image than click on image icon But it don't show any result or any way for me insert my images into my task.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
tinyMCE.init({
    // General options
    mode : "textareas",
    theme : "advanced",

    //plugins : "safari,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template,wordcount",
    editor_selector : "tiny",
    plugins : "safari,pagebreak,style,layer,table,save,advhr,advimage,advlink,emotions,images,iespell,inlinepopups,insertdatetime,preview,media,searchreplace,print,contextmenu,paste,directionality,fullscreen,noneditable,visualchars,nonbreaking,xhtmlxtras,template",

    // Theme options
    theme_advanced_buttons1 : "save,newdocument,|,bold,italic,underline,strikethrough,|,justifyleft,justifycenter,justifyright,justifyfull,styleselect,formatselect,fontselect,fontsizeselect",
    theme_advanced_buttons2 : "cut,copy,paste,pastetext,pasteword,|,search,replace,|,bullist,numlist,|,outdent,indent,blockquote,|,undo,redo,|,link,unlink,anchor,image,images, cleanup,help,code,|,insertdate,inserttime,preview,|,forecolor,backcolor",
    theme_advanced_buttons3 : "tablecontrols,|,hr,removeformat,visualaid,|,sub,sup,|,charmap,emotions,iespell,media,advhr,|,print,|,ltr,rtl,|,fullscreen",
    theme_advanced_buttons4 : "insertlayer,moveforward,movebackward,absolute,|,styleprops,|,cite,abbr,acronym,del,ins,attribs,|,visualchars,nonbreaking,template,pagebreak",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_location : "top",
    theme_advanced_toolbar_align : "left",
    theme_advanced_statusbar_location : "bottom",
    theme_advanced_resizing : true,
});
```

Comment: So If I want images upload feature I have to buy this option right?

Comment: you have to custome the plugins and theme buttons

Comment: Yes I'm alway try to read and find the method for calling it but I can't because it is very deep for me. although like this I still commit to do with it

Comment: You can find it out in their website in [tinymce](http://www.tinymce.com) for more details, i use it in my project and i can say that it is the WYSIWYG editor i need

Comment: Thanks Shen Siddhara and other expert too 
Thanks

Comment: Welcome too @hengsopheak

Answer (score 0):

your "image" is a callback function

```
function myFileBrowser (field_name, url, type, win) {

// alert("Field_Name: " + field_name + "nURL: " + url + "nType: " + type + "nWin: " + win); // debug/testing

/* If you work with sessions in PHP and your client doesn't accept cookies you might need to carry
   the session name and session ID in the request string (can look like this: "?PHPSESSID=88p0n70s9dsknra96qhuk6etm5").
   These lines of code extract the necessary parameters and add them back to the filebrowser URL again. */

var cmsURL = window.location.toString();    // script URL - use an absolute path!
if (cmsURL.indexOf("?") < 0) {
    //add the type as the only query parameter
    cmsURL = cmsURL + "?type=" + type;
}
else {
    //add the type as an additional query parameter
    // (PHP session ID is now included if there is one at all)
    cmsURL = cmsURL + "&type=" + type;
}

tinyMCE.activeEditor.windowManager.open({
    file : cmsURL,
    title : 'My File Browser',
    width : 420,  // Your dimensions may differ - toy around with them!
    height : 400,
    resizable : "yes",
    inline : "yes",  // This parameter only has an effect if you use the inlinepopups plugin!
    close_previous : "no"
}, {
    window : win,
    input : field_name
});
return false;
}
```

and then do

```
tinyMCE.init({
  theme : ...,
  mode: ...,

  file_browser_callback : 'myFileBrowser'
});
```

reference:http://www.tinymce.com/wiki.php/TinyMCE3x:How-to_implement_a_custom_file_browser